# Run Python for Android (Qpython) in Android Terminal

Tags: android, shell, python-2.7, adb, qpython

Python for Android (Py4A 2.6) is wonderful!!! But QPython (2.7) is a lot more powerful and continuously developed. Now I try to integrate Qpython's Python into Android (5.1 CM12) Terminal / ADB described in this Tutorial:http://wiki.qpython.org/en/diveinto/

My Script to import the environment variables qpython needs looks like:

```
TERM=screen
PATH=/data/data/com.hipipal.qpyplus/files/bin:/system/bin:/system/xbin
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.:/data/data/com.hipipal.qpyplus/files/lib/:/data/data/com.hipipal.qpyplus/files/:/data/data/com.hipipal.qpyplus/lib/
PYTHONHOME=/data/data/com.hipipal.qpyplus/files
ANDROID_PRIVATE=/data/data/com.hipipal.qpyplus/files
PYTHONPATH=/storage/emulated/0/com.hipipal.qpyplus/lib/python2.7/site-packages/:/data/data/com.hipipal.qpyplus/files/lib/python2.7/site-packages/:/data/data/com.hipipal.qpyplus/files/lib/python2.7/:/data/data/com.hipipal.qpyplus/files/lib/python27.zip:/data/data/com.hipipal.qpyplus/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/:/storage/emulated/0/com.hipipal.qpyplus/scripts
PYTHONSTARTUP=/storage/emulated/0/com.hipipal.qpyplus/lib/python2.7/site-packages/qpythoninit.py
PYTHONOPTIMIZE=2
TMPDIR=/storage/emulated/0/com.hipipal.qpyplus/cache
AP_HOST=127.0.0.1
AP_PORT=58418
AP_HANDSHAKE=01805a68-c04c-4e21-bd54-ac8732f3a8da
ANDROID_PUBLIC=/storage/emulated/0/com.hipipal.qpyplus
ANDROID_PRIVATE=/data/data/com.hipipal.qpyplus/files
ANDROID_ARGUMENT=/storage/emulated/0/com.hipipal.qpyplus/scripts
```

Shell session:

```
u0_a101@C1905:/ $ source /sdcard/qpyenvnew.sh
u0_a101@C1905:/ $ $python
u0_a101@C1905:/ $ hmm do nothing?!
```

I get no output.

I have found here on Stackoverflow the same Question but the posted solution ist a link how is down.

Other Tutorial on throws only errors  
http://dinostest.com/node/28

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this command in your terminal:

```
$sh data/data/com.hipipal.qpyplus/files/bin/qpython.sh
```

Terminal will prompt a Python console.

Answer (score 1):

If your script for the environment variables was obtained by running the code from the tutorial link, it should be correct.

If what you have pasted is exactly what you entered, the problem would be that you tried to run pyhton by typing `$python` when it should have just been `python`

Pre-fixing with $ is used to reference the value of a variable, so entering `$python` referenced the value of the variable python but does nothing with it, hence no feedback.

Comment: It's clear. I have tryed both. python and $python. I habe copy and paste the Text form the tut.

Comment: the guide on the qpython wiki is for running python in other terminal apps installed on the android device, not ADB shell

Comment: If I try simple things like $python print 2 it works if I launch a script it says I have no execute permission (and chmod +x is not working on droid term)

Comment: @Pitto Try with octal, `chmod 0777 file`. Case you wan't to chmod +x means 7, so, 0755 will be ok for your user, or even root. The chmod implementation of Android don't understand short flags like +x.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT2**: Although it's not a direct answer to this question I suggest having a look at the App 'Termux'. You can install Python2/3 via apt, virtualenv/-wrapper etc... Much more powerfull!

**EDIT**: Since /data/data... is only accessible as root, the following must be done as root! 
Take care that the python executables path is in your $PATH. That wasn't the case even after having run the script from the tutorial (your script). If it's not present simply type:

```
export PATH=/data/data/com.hipipal.qpyplus/files/bin:$PATH
```

or follow [theses steps](https://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Doc:_paths). In short: create a file in /sdcard (here ".bashrc") with the above line. After that type:

```
source .bashrc
source init.sh
```

(init.sh is located in /data/data/com.hipipal.qpyplus/files/bin as well) 
 
Then fire up Python with

```
python-android5
```

which is the PIE compatible executable for Phone with Lollipop and above. But be aware: For whatever reason I couldn't exit() or quit() the Python prompt but I was able to run Script from the Terminal!

Have fun!

Comment: Hey fteinz! Personally I would roll back and perform the above steps. Should be saver and the linker will most likely be overwritten the next time you update your phone...

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** I spotted this: [PythonForAndroid](https://github.com/kuri65536/python-for-android). It is a fork of PythonForAndroid that is still alive, and this versions are able to run on Android L (Python3 on 5.1.1 in my case). Also check the SL4A linked there, it works great on Lollipop.

Thanks to the answers above I made a super easy solution. If you have root: Create a file "python" and type the following line in it:

```
sh data/data/com.hipipal.qpyplus/files/bin/qpython-android5.sh
```

Place this file in your /system/bin directory and you can access python from everywhere using the command 'python'.